# htaccess pretty urls redirects the wrong way

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I've look up for the answer to this question all around the web but I didn't find anyone with the same issue I have.

I want to create a sort of track-order like amazon or like any carrier does. To do that I assign a unique track-number to orders. Users can type the track-number into a form or directly into a url.

I get the track-number via the get method, so I need to prettify urls, but I also want to keep the search form functionality so I need a redirect.

I tried in this way:

the original url: `/order/?reference=track-number` where `track_number` is a random token like `TRG58a8a132ec858`.

the desired url: `/order/track-number` as stated above `track_number` is a random token like `TRG58a8a132ec858`.

in my `.htaccess` I wrote this rule:

```
Rewrite Engine on
RewriteRule ^/?order/([A-Z]{3}.*)/?$ /order/?reference=$1 [L,R=301]
```

I got some inspiration [here](https://24ways.org/2013/url-rewriting-for-the-fearful/), [here](https://gist.github.com/ScottPhillips/1721489), and [here](https://www.gerillafilm.se/web/ultimate-htaccess-rewrite-tutorial-with-301-redirects/).

It works on reverse: when I type the original-url it does not redirect, when I type the desired-url instead it redirects to the original-url.

I am a little bit confused. Where I am making mistakes?

Comment: "when I type the original-url it does not redirect, when I type the desired-url instead it redirects to the original-url." -- isn't this what it's suppose to do? So when you type `/order/track-number` it points to `/order/?reference=track-number` instead?

Comment: @A.Zheng as I said, when I type the original url (which is not pretty at all) it does not redirect to the pretty url. so no, it is not supposed to work that way and yes,`/order/TRG58a8a132ec858` redirects to `/order/?reference=TRG58a8a132ec858` which is wrong. `/order/?reference=TRG58a8a132ec858` should redirect to `/order/TRG58a8a132ec858` not vice versa!

Comment: hmm I think there's a misunderstanding, usually when you do a url rewrite, you want to mask your ugly url with a fake url, that does not really exist, but is created by the server rewrite rule. So that is how it's suppose to function. When you type `/order/track-number` the rewrite rule is telling the server to fetch `/order/?reference=track-number` which does exist. This is not a "redirect" in the sense that there's no real `/order/track-number` page for it to redirect from. Your server is handling this behind the scene.

Comment: Yes. OK. So why if the user type the ugly URL it does not redirect to the pretty URL?

Comment: well I mean, if you *really* want that behavior, you could switch order of your rule, so that the ugly url comes first, then the desired, 'cause the rule is `RewriteRule [match url] [redirect to url]` but I'm pretty sure you want it so that no user ever has to see the ugly url, so they'd type in the desired url instead, which really fetches the ugly one behind the scenes.